# on html keyup i want to call a php page and get the variable value from there and add it to an HTML content

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I know its super basic and probably simple as well, but i'm really stuck.
just trying to get data from php in an event of onkeyup, and post it into the HTML page.

this is my HTML

```
<input id="dell" type="text" onkeyup="dell_function()"<br>

<p id="gimr">get her the php variable var.</p>
```

php file:

```
<?
$var=11;
echo $var;
?>
```

Now i need to write the dell_function() which i want to open the php file and get the $var value, and post it as a string in here:

```
<p id="gimr">get her the php variable var.</p>
```

i know there is ajax involved but i really tried but couldn't figure it out, so how do i write the dell_function?

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Try exploring Ajax. As mentioned by @JayBlanchard, it is better to try yourself first. In case you face any error, then post the question for solution.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to Stack Overflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ajax is really simple, especially if you are using JQuery. Here is how it would look in jQuery:

```
function dell_function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"test.php", // replace test.php with the name of your PHP file
        success: function(data) {
                     $("#gimr").html(data);
                 }
    });
}
```

The jQuery documentation describes loads of other cool things you can do with Ajax : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thanks for the feedback. When I get a bit of time I'll edit my answer and make it a little more clear.

Answer (score -1):

```
function dell_function() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // creates a ajax request object
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () { // will fire when the status of the request changes
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { // checks if the current state indicates that the content has been loaded successfully. readyState=4 means that the request has been completed and the status 200 means that the request returned http status code 200, which means the server response is OK (404 would mean file not found, 408 means timeout, etc - you get the idea).
            document.getElementById("gimr").innerHTML = this.responseText; //this will put the response text as html inside the "gimr" element.
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "YOUR_PHP_FILE.php", true); //the first parameter sets the request method, the second defines the url, and the third defines if the data should be fetched asynchronously.
    xhttp.send(); // sends the requests to the specified url.
}
```

Replace "YOUR_PHP_FILE.php" with the url to your php file.

Btw, take a look at jquery - it makes things like this alot easier ;D

Comment: A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.